# Spring boot health check redirecting to Sign on page on Boot upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

> Getting health check link redirected to Sign on Page after boot upgrade

> Need help to prevent health check link getting redirected to sign on page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. in application.yml, change mgmt port to another port for security and add a base-path such as '/mgmt' to do easily in second step.

```yaml
management:
  server:
    port: 12000 # diffrent from server.port
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /mgmt
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

2. config ignore in SecurityConfiguration as below

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       String [] notauthlist = {"/mgmt/**"};
       web.ignoring().antMatchers(notauthlist);
    }
}
```